# Wpf uniform grid item

Tags: c#, wpf

I have uniform grid, with buttons and labels. Each button has unique content, after clicking on the button situated in the box I want to change label in this box. But how can i figure out in which box button was clicked and which label need to change?

```
namespace WpfApplication107
{
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new Shop();
    }
}

public class StructOfBox
{
    public string Size { get; set; }
    public string Amount { get; set; }
    public ICommand ChangeSize { get; set; }
}

public class Shop
{
    public Shop()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<StructOfBox>();
        Items.Add(new StructOfBox { Amount = "0", Size = "S", ChangeSize = new RelayCommand(() => ChangeAmount()) });
        Items.Add(new StructOfBox { Amount = "0", Size = "M", ChangeSize = new RelayCommand(() => ChangeAmount()) });
        Items.Add(new StructOfBox { Amount = "0", Size = "L", ChangeSize = new RelayCommand(() => ChangeAmount()) });
        Items.Add(new StructOfBox { Amount = "0", Size = "XL", ChangeSize = new RelayCommand(() => ChangeAmount()) });
    }

    public ObservableCollection<StructOfBox> Items { get; set; }
    public void ChangeAmount()
    {
        // what box?
        Debug.WriteLine("pressed");
    }
}
}
```

Xaml:

```
 <Grid>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Columns="2" Rows="2"></UniformGrid>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Green">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Button Content="{Binding Size}" Command="{Binding ChangeSize}"></Button>
                        <Label Content="{Binding Amount}" Height="25" Grid.Row="2"></Label>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

Comment: show xaml file also pleaase

Comment: Just change the `Amount` property in the `ChangeSize` command execute handler. Note that your StructOfBox class needs to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface to update the UI.

Comment: you could bind/set the Label to the Button's tag. When the button is pressed you'd only have to cast the event object (o) to a button and then cast it's tag to a Label.

Comment: @SteffenWinkler Why should they do this when there is already a view model with a command in place? Your suggestion would require to add a Click handler to the Button that already has a Command Binding.

Comment: @Clemens sorry but I've never worked with Commands before. Already wondered where the Click eventhandler was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would pass the "calling" StructOfBox as a parameter to the ChangeAmount() handler. That way you would be able to change the label without really needing to know which button was clicked.

But as Clemens said, in order for this to work correctly, StructOfBox will have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: You don't need to pass the current StructOfBox item to the command, because the command is already a property of StructOfBox. The execute method of the command should simply be a method of StructOfBox and would hence get the current item by `this`.

Comment: That would actually make sense. Unless he really needs to keep the "handler" outside the class.